# How can I take the value before in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I've wrote a program with 2 variables with a `for x in range(0,100,1)`

And I would like to know, how to take the previous value of the output.

For example:

`a` will take this values: `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9`

and `b` will take: `0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8`

I thought at somethings like `b = a-1` but doesnt work than

Comment: Toss in your actual code of what you've got.  Even better https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What happens when you try `b = a-1` that makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to add the code. Do not add your code in the comments. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` two ranges that start on values that differ by 1:

```
for a, b in zip(range(1, 10), range(10)):
    print(a, b)
```

This outputs:

```
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4
6 5
7 6
8 7
9 8
```